# Function of set.seed in this Monte Carlo Simulation (R)

Tags: r, montecarlo

I have some questions regarding how this code works. It is both a stats and coding question so please let me know if I should take this to the stats part of stack exchange. I knew what code to write to get the answer, but what the code returned does not make sense to me. Here is the question

Q:Assume you are testing the effectiveness of 20 diets on mice weight. For each of the 20 diets you run an experiment with 10 control mice and 10 treated mice. Assume the null hypothesis that the diet has no effect is true for all 20 diets and that mice weights follow a normal distribution with mean 30 grams and a standard deviation of 2 grams, run a Monte Carlo simulation for one of these studies:

```
cases = rnorm(10,30,2)
controls = rnorm(10,30,2)
t.test(cases,controls)
```

Now run a Monte Carlo simulation imitating the results for the experiment for all 20 diets. If you set the seed at 100, set.seed(100), and use the same code as above inside a call to replicate how many of p-values (number not proportion) are below 0.05?"

Here is the code the I wrote

```
set.seed(100)
pvals <- replicate(20,{
  cases = rnorm(10,30,2)
  controls = rnorm(10,30,2)
  t.test(cases,controls)$p.val
})
sum(pvals<.05)
```

First off, my coding question is why do I need the set.seed(100) part? Doesn't replicate do everything for me here? When I reran the code while commenting out the set.seed part the answer, which is 1, did not change so I'm confused what use the set.seed has here.

Second, this question sounds stats related, but I think it has to do more with the code. The answer returned by the `sum(pvals<.o5)` part is always 1 even after I run it multiple times, which is confusing because I thought p values are random and over multiple random comparisons the p values will vary. Why is it always just 1 p value that is below .05 in this simulation every time I run it?

Comment: Rerun the code multiple times, without resetting the seed to 100 each time, and you should see different answers, and most importantly, different values of `pvals` each time. In 10 or so runs, I see a few values of 0, 1 and 2. It shouldn't always be 1, unless you are setting the seed to generate the exact same set of random samples each time. Once you've tried that out, decide which part of the question you still need help with and edit it to reflect that.

Comment: `set.seed(100)` ensures that someone else can reproduce the same results of the simulation.